# Add Collection to End of IOrderedEnumerable

Tags: c#, xml, linq, iorderedenumerable

I currently have a bunch of config files I need to load into an IOrderedEnumerable My current approach looks like so:

```
foreach (var item in configFiles)
{
    XDocument myxml = XDocument.Load(item);
    var items = myxml.Root.Elements("Item");
    Items = items.OrderBy(x => x.Attribute("ID").Value);
    ItemsLength += Items.Count();              
}
```

The problem is, instead of making `Items` equal to `items.OrderBy(x => x.Attribute("ID").Value)` I'd like to join that to the end of the currently existing IOrderedEnumerable so I'm not overwriting it each time I load a new XDocument and get all of the elements from it. How would I do this?

EDIT: I know that if I change this `ItemsLength += Items.Count();` will no longer function properly. That's something I'll change on my own.

Comment: What's the *ultimate* aim here - are you trying to get all items ordered by `ID`, or only ordered by ID *within their document*. It's unclear what you're really trying to achieve. (I doubt that you really need an `IOrderedEnumerable` - that's just what OrderBy returns. What are you doing with it afterwards? I would expect an `IEnumerable` to be enough.)

Comment: Only ordered by ID within their document.

Comment: I would suggest just putting all of the items together and then ordering them all once at the end.  If you have some attribute that represents the document you can order by that, and then just add a `ThenBy` for the ID.

Comment: EDIT: I should probably rephrase that. Say I have multiple configs. As it is, config 1 will only contain, as an example, values 1-60 (any arbitrary amount will do), config 2 will start on value 61 and go to value 70 (so values 61 - 70), and config 3 will contain values 71-100. I understand I could keep all values in a single config but that's arbitrary to the question. The values in the configs should be ordered as it is. `Orderby()`'s just a safety measure if anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the whole thing declaratively:

```
Items = configFiles.Select((item, index) => new { Doc = XDocument.Parse(item),
                                                  Index = index })
                   .SelectMany(pair => pair.Doc.Root.Elements("Item")
                                           .Select(x => new { Item = x, 
                                                              Index = pair.Index }))
                   .OrderBy(pair => pair.Index)
                   .ThenBy(pair => (string) pair.Attribute("ID"))
                   .Select(pair => pair.Item);
```

This basically finds *all* the elements, but remembers which configuration each is in.

Alternatively, just create a `List<XElement>` and add each item's contents:

```
var items = new List<XElement>();
foreach (var item in configFiles)
{
    items.AddRange(XDocument.Parse(item)
                            .Root.Elements("Item")
                            .OrderBy(x => (string) x.Attribute("ID")));
}
Items = items;
```

In some ways that's less elegant, but it's probably easier to understand :)

Comment: Your query needs to select the item back out of the anon objects holding onto the index, at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change `Items` to be of type `IEnumerable` rather than `IOrderedEnumerable`, you could use `Concat`:

```
Items = Items.Concat(items.OrderBy(x => x.Attribute("ID").Value));
```

This would keep items sorted by `ID` within their own document.

Note that using `Concat` in a loop may impair the performance. You would be better off declaring `Items` as `IList`, and calling `ToList` at the end of each iteration:

```
Items.AddRange(items.OrderBy(x => x.Attribute("ID").Value));
```

Comment: If you're going to make `Items` a list you'd be better off just using `AddRange` to add the new documents' items, rather than creating a new list each time.